# Wrong time calculated having more than 30min

Tags: php, time, calculator

Im having a a bit strange problem, Im having this code and on output it adds always one hour more if the second time has 30 or more minutes.

```
$time1 = '12:00';
$time2 = '13:30';
list($hours, $minutes) = explode(':', $time1);
$startTimestamp = mktime($hours, $minutes);

list($hours, $minutes) = explode(':', $time2);
$endTimestamp = mktime($hours, $minutes);

$seconds = $endTimestamp - $startTimestamp;
$minutes = ($seconds / 60) % 60;
$hours = round($seconds / (60 * 60));
```

Whats happening here?

Comment: What is the result and what is you suppose to be?

Comment: 01:30 hour, but it comes to 2:30.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `round` use `intval` as `$seconds / (60 * 60)` expression always returns a float and we need only the integer part of that result

Comment: @middaparka - $seconds / (60 * 60) expression always returns a float and we need only the integer part of that result. And yes, I agree, it was a lazy answer.

Answer (score 2):

Remember the math. Rounding up everything in interval [0.5;1) equals to 1.

```
round(0.5) = 1
```

That's why you've +1 hour in case of minutes in [30;60].

Comment: Ok, thanks I see the mistake. I should use the intval instead then?